# Create database from backup file

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I have a full backup file from my database. I want to create new database from this file. The two databases are in different server when I restore the file I got this error

> The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.2550. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.5512. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.

How should I do?

please help

Comment: what you didn't understand in that message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backup was made on a server running SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (10.50.2550), but you are trying to restore it to an instance running SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 3 (10.00.55xx).

Upgrade your local instance to be SQL Server 2008 R2 and everything should work.

Source: http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql Database, for that HaidiSQL is the client for providing the user interface to handle the database. So please download it and follow the following steps.

```
1) Open the HaidiSQL

2) select the **Tool** menu

3) select  **Load SQL file** or Ctrl+O

4) Open window will dispaly

5) Select your backup file.

6) On the tool bar blue color triangle is there please click on it. OR Press F9 button on keyboard.
```

Your back up file create the database in your MySQL.